# Using javascript for video source into HTML5 video player

Tags: javascript, html, video, html5-video

When I open the page in a browser, on occasions the video does not load and also if I refresh the page the video never loads, how can I fix these 2 issues?

This is the html for my video player

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
                <source id="audioFile" src="" type="video/mp4">
                Your brow
```

This is the javascript code which gets the name of the video file from the URL

```
function getUrlParameters(parameter, staticURL, decode){
            var currLocation = (staticURL.length)? staticURL : window.location.search,
            parArr = currLocation.split("?")[1].split("&"),
            returnBool = true;
            for(var i = 0; i < parArr.length; i++){
                parr = parArr[i].split("=");
                if(parr[0] == parameter){
                    return (decode) ? decodeURIComponent(parr[1]) : parr[1];
                    returnBool = true;
                }else{
                    returnBool = false;
                }
            }
            if(!returnBool) return false;
        }
        var parameter = getUrlParameters("audioFile", "", true);
        document.getElementById('audioFile').src = parameter;
        document.getElementById('url').content = parameter;
```

Comment: are you asking how to change the src?

Comment: No I'm asking how to fix the issues of the video not loading sometimes and when I refresh the page.

Comment: After you set the `src`, try running `document.getElementById('video').load()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Dynamically modifying a `source` element and its attribute when the element is already inserted in a `video` or `audio` element will have no effect. To change what is playing, just use the `src` attribute on the media element directly <...>
>
> [The `source` element](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-video-element.html#the-source-element)

Either change the `src` attribute of the  `video` element (this will call the `load()` method implicitly):

```
var parameter = getUrlParameters("audioFile", "", true);
document.querySelector('video').src = parameter;
```

or call the `load()` method explicitly:

```
var parameter = getUrlParameters("audioFile", "", true);
document.getElementById('audioFile').src = parameter;
document.querySelector('video').load();
```